# Refusal of Visit Visa - UK

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I have a few questions about the attached documents below:

1. Can I reapply within 15 days (fast track application)?
2. I am the owner of two companies, but I thought to apply as an employee. When they checked my statements, they couldn't find any salary credits but there are other credits. Will providing the incorporation certificate, AOA and MOA support that I will come back - as these business are here only? The ITR of the company is not filed, its still on progress.
3. I am supporting my sister financially since April with a monthly credit of Rs 55 K and I have now transferred Rs 2 Lakhs to support her airline and other expenses of the trip. Will providing that info help?
4. I applied for 70 days initially; can I cut this short to e.g. 30 days? If that is the case, is it necessary I leave after 30 days, irrespective of the six months validity of visa if granted?
5. I just want to visit my sister and come back within 30 days, no intention to stay there.

[Page 1 of Refusal Letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfwBe.jpg)

[Page 2 of Refusal Letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3zA5.jpg)

[Invitation from Sister](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkuxS.jpg)

[Cover Letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnkXe.jpg)

Content I entered on the form:

> Are you travelling with anyone?   No
>   Date of planned arrival in the UK   06 Dec 2017
>   How long do you intend to stay in the UK?   70 DAYS
>   What is the main address and contact details of where you will be staying whilst in the UK? xxxxxxxx
>   What is your current working status?    Employed Full Time
>   What is your total monthly income from all sources of employment or occupation, after tax?  INR 65000
>   When did you start this job?    01 Apr 2015
>   Do you have any additional paid jobs or occupations?    No
>
> Income and Expenditure
>   Do you have savings, properties or other income, for example from stocks and shares?    No
>   How much do you spend each month on living costs?   GBP 233
>   How much of your total monthly income is given to your family members and other dependants? NIL
>   What is the cost to you personally of your trip in GBP(£)?  GBP 584
>   The total amount of money you have for this trip    GBP 584
>   The cost of the aeroplane, boat or train tickets    SPONSOR
>   The cost of your accommodation  SPONSOR
>   The cost of your living expenses    SPONSOR
>   Is someone other than you paying for all or a part of your trip?    Yes
>   Please select what the relationship is of the person who is contributing to the payment for your trip?  Sister
>   How much will they be paying towards your trip (in GBP £)?  SPONSOR
>   Please explain why they are paying towards the cost of your trip?   SHE IS MY SISTER
>   What is the total amount in GBP(£)? SPONSOR
>
> Family and Friends in the UK
>   Family and Friends
>   Please enter details of what you plan to do whilst in the UK    TO VISIT MY SIBLING AND CELEBRATE CHRISTMAS AND NEW YEAR HOLIDAYS
>   Do you have any friends or family in the UK?    Yes
>   Relationship    Sister
>   Family Name xxxxxx
>   Given Name  xxxxxxx
>   Nationality INDIA
>   Status in the UK    Temporary Resident
>   Address 1   xxxxxxxx
>   Address 2   ENIFIELD
>   Address 3   UNITED KINGDOM
>   Address 4   
>   Postal Code EN11EU
>   Primary Contact Number  xxxxxxxx
>   Secondary Contact Number
>   Email   
>   Visit or Stay   Yes

Answer (score 5):

You should read the information at [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) Because reading your refusal letter, there are significant issues with your finances, and I wouldn't reapply until you can straighten that out, legitimately, and apply with bank statements that show a stable and coherent financial history.

What they're looking for is an organized set of financials where everything makes sense. You say that you're an employee earning £759/month, they expect to see payslips that show around £759/month, bank statements that show deposits of around £759/month, tax paperwork that shows around £759/month, etc... None of your numbers add up; your payslips, bank account, and tax papers all say different things. If you own the businesses, you should provide the documentation for that, but you need to be able to provide a coherent explanation for how much money you, personally, earn, and to be able to prove that with the documents you submit.

Frankly, that you have one month's salary in the bank and plan to spend most of it on your trip is concerning.

I am also confused about how you are supporting your sister. Your application says your sister is paying for your trip. But your question here says that you are supporting your sister financially. She's sponsoring your trip, but you just gave her around three times your monthly income to pay for your own travel expenses? That's just sponsoring your own trip, but moving money around for no apparent reason. None of this makes sense.

Also, this:

> How much will they be paying towards your trip (in GBP £)? SPONSOR

Makes no sense. They want to know how much your sponsor will be spending for your trip, as in an actual amount of money.

You can apply again at any time, and pay for priority service if you wish, but as the refusal letter says: "you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances of your application change."

You can make your next application for a shorter trip if you wish, though that won't solve any of these problems. In general, I would stick to the itinerary provided with your visa application, even if the visa is issued for a six month period. We've seen people [be refused future visas](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87229/uk-visitor-visa-refused-due-to-previously-staying-for-too-long-and-not-having-st) if they stay significantly longer.

Comment: The other question you will need to address is that of how you can afford to take 70 days away from your job? I know you own the company, but presumably you do some work to deserve your salary. What happens to the company  if it is not done? If the answer is that the company does not need you to be present, that immediately raises the question of why you would need to return to your country at all, which would be a problem for your application.

Comment: Also, _"How much of your total monthly income is given to your family members and other dependants? NIL"_ would appear to be a blatant lie, unless the OP lying _to us_ about supporting their sister financially (to the tune of 85% of their monthly post-tax income!).