# When I enter the UK on a work visa, can my mother go with me on a visitor visa?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, working-visas

I have submitted my application for a Tier 2 ICT employer sponsored visa. While this is in process, can I start the standard visitor visa application for my mother who would be traveling with me and staying with me in UK for 6 months? She is a housewife and I would be taking care of all her travel and stay expenses.

What is the process to apply for my mother and what documents need to be submitted to avoid refusal. Can I start her visa process along with my visa process?

Comment: You should tell us where you are from, but 6 months is a very long visit. On the face of it, this application sounds highly likely to be refused.

Comment: @Shree Details of the visitor visa requirements are here https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa There’s little point applying for your mother’s visitor visa until you know whether your Tier2 visa has been approved - your mother has no premise for her visit without that. I agree with MJeffryes, on the basis of the information in your question a 6 month-long visit sounds highly likely to be refused

Comment: Classic case of counting ones chicks before they hatch.

Comment: @MJeffryes what is the solution then in this case,

Comment: @shree Plan a much shorter visit for your mother (3 weeks at most), and include evidence that she will return back to her home country at the end of the holiday. Note that if her visa is granted on the premise that she will stay 3 weeks, she will still get a 6 month visa *but she should stay as long as she said she would, not 6 months*, or future applications will be refused. This site has lots of answers about this subject, search for “uk visa ties” and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/87229/uk-visitor-visa-refused-due-to-previously-staying-for-too-long-and-not-having-st

Comment: MJeffryes once i get  my visa can we look for applying 3 months visa for my mother? Or is it  better to initiate mother's visa process AFTER 2 months of my landing?

Comment: @Shree You having a visa doesn't actually help your mother get one, but if your visa application ends up being refused, then you've wasted the money on your mother's application. Also, as I said, a trip measured in months is less likely to be approved than one that lasts a couple of weeks. And once again, please read the answers to the question I linked carefully, do not be tempted to have your mother stay longer than planned once she's approved for a six month visa on the premise of a shorter holiday. She must only stay for the length of time she said she would stay.

Answer (score 1):

One, you could ask a solicitor, this should be *extremely* simple and quick for one and I would expect it to cost no more than 75-100 GBP for a quick phone call.

But if you are asking random strangers on the Internet then we will tell you for free that a) you should not be taking life altering advice from random strangers on the Internet b) such a visa is extremely likely to be denied. Reason is, your mother will effectively be an unpaid worker for you, providing many services which you might need to pay for otherwise thus she would be actively harmful to the UK economy and they would never allow that. She cooks a meal for you and you eat home instead of eating out? Well, you just denied income to a restaurant. And so forth. Yes, it's possible you'd be super frugal and no such thing would happen otherwise but they can't know that.