# Am I breaking laws staying longer than the intended dates on visit visa in the uk?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, spouses

With a UK tourist visit visa if I specified on the visa application I would be staying 2 weeks and then successfully get the visa but once in the UK I decide to stay for 4 months am I breaking any law? Does this class as deception or anything like that?

I’m guessing not as the visa is 6 months and intended dates are just intended travel dates and not a definite date I must travel by.

I know this can affect figure visit visas but that’s fine, was just wondering if I’m breaking any rules or laws doing this which would affect me applying for say a spouse visa in the future? I do plan to apply for a spouse visa and was hoping this longer than intended uk visit visa stay won’t affect it.
I’ve had a look at the immigration laws and I can’t seem to find anything that would lead to it being an issue

Comment: See related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/170145/will-staying-longer-than-specified-on-a-uk-visit-visa-affect-a-future-spouse-vis

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it, staying longer than originally planned as a visitor but leaving within the 6 months’ visa validity period does not breach any Immigration Rules.

The UK makes a distinction between information that is false but where the ECO is not satisfied there was an intention to deceive by the applicant and cases where the ECO is satisfied there was deception by the applicant.

Visa decisions are made on the basis of the information provided in the application *at the time* the application is made. If, for example, an applicant stated they planned to stay 2 weeks and showed intention to leave by proving they had a job to return to, and then on receipt of their visa resigned their job to be able to stay (much) longer, such a material change in circumstances and non-disclosure of it at the time of seeking entry to the UK *might* be construed as false representation or deception. Note: IANAL.

https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/947434/Suitability-false-representations-v2.0ext.pdf